# How to show input fields based on select options?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to show input fields based on select value but it's not working. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```js
$('#milkoptions').on('change', function(){
   if($(this).val()==="milkfatrate") {
       $("#milkfatrateoptions").show()
   }
    else{
        $("#milkfatrateoptions").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="milkoptions">
        <option value="default-value">Select your option</option>
        <option value="milkfatrate">Milk by Fat Rate</option>
   </select>
</div> 
<div id="milkfatrateoptions" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="entry-date" class="form-control" name="milk-quantity" placeholder="Milk 
        Quantity">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="entry-date" class="form-control" name="milk-fat" placeholder="Milk Fat">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/0Lk1qbvt/ Did you make sure that your JS code executes _after_ the select field already exists?

Comment: can you please add your error description?

Comment: Figured it out! I was executing the script code before jquery file